# Bundle package is not working in TideSDK

Tags: titanium, tidesdk

i have developed a simple desktop application using **TideSDK(1.3.1-beta) and TideSDK developer(1.4.2)**
for windows platform.i packed my application as bundle package.its running well in my machine.but it shows following **error message** when i **execute it in other machines.**

Error message during execution on another machine

**This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.reinstalling the application may fix this problem**

Answer (score -1):

Same issue appeared just today.
Try installing vc redist 2010 + vc redist 2012. It helped in my case

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think this might help to resolve the issue? What is the root cause? Installation was already proposed by the error message ...